# What can I do with my Y-DNA marker file from LivingDNA?

Tags: y-dna, living-dna

I took the 3-in-1 test from LivingDNA. The Y DNA result was a haplogroup, plus a 405-line text file that looks like this in part

```
F82/M620
F93/M621/PF6114
FGC41/Y108/M12190
IMS-JST00305/F719/M3636/S8235
L1004
L1013
L1053
```

It's sorted alphabetically, and there's lots of CTS, M, P, PF and Z.

The file format isn't accepted by FTDNA, Yfull, GEDmatch, or in fact any other site I know of.  LivingDNA itself appears to offer no Y-chromosome matching either.

Is there any way I can use this file to help break down my fatherline brickwall (Ireland mid 1800s) or put it to any other use ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not completely clear from the LivingDNA website, but it looks like the autosomal raw data file includes the Y-DNA SNPs. I don't think that is the file you are referring to, but must be another file they allow you to download. If that is correct then you can upload the autosomal file to the [Y-DNA Warehouse](https://ydna-warehouse.org/submit.php). This is a site run by volunteers/citizen scientists who might use your data in their research. This will probably not immediately give you any insights about your male line brickwall, but might eventually lead to something. Depending on your exact haplogroup you might also look at [ytree.net](https://www.ytree.net/). If you find your branch on that tree, the ancestry of the other close branch members might help you with your research.